# Office AddIn in Store is NOT visible in Excel Online

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, excel-addins, office-js

we have submited successfully an Office AddIn in the Office Store.

Through the Requirements in our Manifest our app should be availale in the following Office products:

- Word
- Excel
- **Excel Online**

***Our Office AddIn is NOT listed in Excel Online!?***

When we deploy through our internal Sharepoint this works as desired (App in Excel Online, NOT in Word Online ).

The Manifest of our Store-Upload looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
    <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
      <Id>925fda0f-5c39-49a8-85fe-0e9aad7cb71f</Id>
      <Version>2.0.0.0</Version>
      <ProviderName>XXX Name</ProviderName>
      <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
      <DisplayName DefaultValue="DISP-NAME" />
      <Description DefaultValue="Bla bla."/>
      <IconUrl DefaultValue="URI/Images/app32x32.png" />
      <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="URI/Images/app64x64.png" />
      <RequestedWidth>320</RequestedWidth>
      <SupportUrl DefaultValue="URL" />

        <Hosts>
          <Host Name="Document" />
          <Host Name="Workbook" />
        </Hosts>
        <Requirements>
            <Sets>
                <Set Name="TableBindings" MinVersion="1.1" />
                <Set Name="Settings" MinVersion="1.1" />
                <Set Name="Selection" MinVersion="1.1" />
               <Set Name="TextCoercion" MinVersion="1.1" />
            </Sets>
             <Methods>
                    <Method Name="Document.goToByIdAsync"/>  <!-- blocks Word Online -->
              </Methods>            
        </Requirements>

        <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="URI/Index.html" />
            <!--<SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Index.html" />-->
            <!--<SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/appdirectory-build/Index.html" />-->
      </DefaultSettings>
      <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
    </OfficeApp>
```

(Some privat informations are removed in the Manifest)

**Any ideas why our Office AddIn is NOT listed in Excel Online by the store!?**

Comment: Seems Microsoft is not interested on developing office apps - no reaction in MSDN and here !?

Comment: I'm forwarding this internally to the team that owns the Office Store, to see if they can investigate

Comment: Also, in terms of an investigation, it may be helpful if you can provide the name of your add-in so that the team can look it up and repro locally (unless you'd prefer to keep it private).

Comment: Hi Michael, the name of the app is "IDL.OFFICELINK" (https://store.office.com/idl-officelink-WA104379572.aspx?assetid=WA104379572&sourcecorrid=0335b07f-3e70-4a89-b071-b1d7b583cb2b&searchapppos=0). You may contact me directly if you need further information.